# NSTimer to display background colors with a delay

Tags: swift, nstimer

Trying to get this to display the background colors with a delay, but it jumps to the last one. I thought the timer would allow time before each iteration. What am I missing?

```
func displayLevel() {

        status.setText("Watch the sequence.")

            color = UIColor()

            for (value, number) in gameArray.enumerate() {

                if value == 0 {
                    color = UIColor.redColor()
                } else if value == 1 {
                    color = UIColor.greenColor()
                } else if value == 2 {
                    color = UIColor.blueColor()
                } else if value == 3 {
                    color = UIColor.yellowColor()

                self.gameButton.setBackgroundColor(color)

            }

        }

    }

    func startTimer() {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(speed, target: self, selector: "displayLevel", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
```

Comment: self.gameButton.setBackgroundColor(color) This should be outside of last else if block

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `self.gameButton.setBackgroundColor(color)` inside the if statement.

You should move `self.gameButton.setBackgroundColor(color)` outside the if statement but still inside the for loop. Thus get the last `}` behind `self.gameButton.setBackgroundColor(color)` and paste it in front of the `self.gameButton.setBackgroundColor(color)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the colors to display based upon the timer interval, you need to set up a repeating timer.  Then `displayLevel()` will be called each time the color is to change.  Increment `value` for the next go around and then invalidate the timer when you've reached the end:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var value = 0
    var timer: NSTimer?
    let speed = 0.5

    func startTimer() {
        value = 0
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(speed, target: self,
            selector: "displayLevel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func displayLevel() {
        let color: UIColor

        switch value {
        case 0: color = .redColor()
        case 1: color = .greenColor()
        case 2: color = .blueColor()
        default:
            color = .yellowColor()

            // We've reached the last color.  Turn off the timer.
            timer?.invalidate()
        }

        self.gameButton.backgroundColor = color

        // increment value for next go around
        value++
    }
}
```